# Unable to get the parameters sent from POST request

Tags: php, api, post, postman, slim

I'm trying to retrieve a POST request sent using POSTMAN. I'm able to retrieve the value of all other parameters  but not getting the value of email. What could be wrong with my code?

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->post('/instituteRegister', function(Request $request , Response 
$response){
$irno = $request->getParam('irno');
$iname = $request->getParam('iname');
$iaddress = $request->getParam('iaddress');
$state = $request->getParam('state');
$district = $request->getParam('district');
$ipno  = $request->getParam('ipno');
$email = $request->getParam('email');
$password = $request->getParam('password');
//echo $code ."<br>";

echo $irno ." <= irno <br>";
echo $iname ." <= iname <br>";
echo $iaddress ." <= iaddress <br>";
echo $state ." <= state <br>";
echo $district . "<= district <br>";
echo $ipno ." <= ipno <br>";
echo $email . " <= email <br>";
echo $password . " <= password <br>";
);
```

Using postman I sent the post request as in the image below 
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quiJX.jpg)

Why is the email field blank?
POST : http://localhost/EOnlineService/api/v1/institution/institution.php/instituteRegister?irno=12&iname=grace&iaddress=xyz&state=kohima&district=xyz&ipno=12&email =grace@gmaill.com&password=hello123

Answer (score 0):

`@` sign in email can be a problem, url encode the email address and check the output. `grace%40gmail.com`

I would suggest to pass this data as json raw body in `post` request because of the length limitation of url.

Comment: It doesnt work . I even tried without any special characters but still no luck

Comment: try `print_r($request); ` to check all the query params in request. and post the slim request object here to investigate further.

Comment: Is there a way to decode the json data sent from the client  using the "request" object ?

Comment: The value for email is blank  after checking the query param in print_r($request)  ouput

Answer (score 0):

### REQUEST

$email="xyz@gmail.com";
$encodedEmail=urlencode($email);

### ANSWER

$decodedEmail = urldecode($_GET['email']); // It will return xyz@gmail.com as a string, decoded.

Comment: Doesn't work, I even tried to give the value of email without any special character. Eg email=gracegmailcom

Comment: strange, normaly it should return the params, can you var_dump the request?

Comment: I think the problem was because of the limitation length of the URL. Passing the POST data as json did the work. Thanks for the help